# Getting non-zero data and positions from 2D array in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D array, and I hope I can get all of the non-zero data and their position. But now I just can get the non-zero data position.

Is there any way that I can get the value and the position at the same time?

```
import numpy as np

groupMatrix = np.array([
[1, 1, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 2],
[3, 3, 0, 2]
])

res = zip(*np.nonzero(groupMatrix))

print(list(res))
```

The result I got is [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 3), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 3)]

But I hope the result can show the position with value.

For example, (x, y, z): x, y represent the position and z represents the value at the point.

(0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1), (2, 3, 2), (3, 0, 3), (3, 1, 3), (3, 3, 2).

Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: Why use a list comprehension with numpy objects? The whole class is built to avoid doing exactlhy that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`np.vstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) and [numpy multidimensional indexing.](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

```
i   = np.nonzero(arr)

res = np.vstack([i, arr[i]])
```

---

```
array([[0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3],
       [0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 3],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2]])
```

If you *really* need a *list of tuples* with the information, you can use `list(zip(*...))`

```
>>> list(zip(*res))
[(0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1), (2, 3, 2), (3, 0, 3), (3, 1, 3), (3, 3, 2)]
```

Comment: The misplacement of `*` was a typo. The idea of `vstack` is exactly to avoid using `list(zip(*...))`. It is supposed to be not an "extra" step, but the final step. I've added the last bit just if OP _reaaally_ needed to have a list of tuples. Nonetheless, holding a 2-D numpy object sounds like a way better idea to me than a list of tuples, for future use.

Answer (score 2):

```
print(list(zip(*np.nonzero(groupMatrix),groupMatrix[groupMatrix!=0])))
```

This is certainly not the most efficient solution (it replicates the search for nonzero elements), but it works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

If your arrays are small, like the one in your question, [`ndenumerate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndenumerate.html) will  be readable and fast.  If your arrays are large, you should default to vectorized methods.

---

```
[(*i, j) for i, j in np.ndenumerate(arr) if j != 0]
```

```
[(0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1), (2, 3, 2), (3, 0, 3), (3, 1, 3), (3, 3, 2)]
```